# can anyone help me to create ternary numbers of digits 0,1,2?

Tags: c#, math, iteration

I want to create a list of  number combinations which consists of only three digits `(0, 1, 2)`. If `n=1` then the result is like this `{0, 1, 2}` .If `n=2` then result is `{00, 01,02, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22}` . If `n=3` the result will be like `{000,001 etc 222}`. I have tried to create this function using recursion. but i failed to create.How can I use iterations to create such list.

Comment: Eric Lippert has a [nice blog](https://ericlippert.com/2013/04/15/producing-permutations-part-one/) on permutations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recursive approach could work well here, If you are running out of memory you might be going about it the rong way or you might just have a bug.

If you want to do this by iteration you can look at the problem this way: you want all the numbers from 0 to `3^n - 1` in base 3. now you just need to [convert to base 3](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/recurrence/conversion.shtml) (and pad with 0s)

Answer (score 0):

Try converting to strings, checking the (length <= n), and prepending (n - length) 0's if necessary.
[EDIT] That is, assuming you are talking about the formatting...
[EDIT v2] I am sure this is not the fastest way to do it, but you could recursively list all numbers from 0 - x and use the aforementioned string methods to iterate over the numbers an check whether any characters other than 0 - n are used.

Comment: yes... i have tried recursion. but the memory usage is too large... if n>10.  how could i code this using iterations.

Comment: The memory usage to assemble the strings? 3^10 = 59049, so even if they're given a huge over-estimate of 256 bytes each that's only 14MB. Do you actually need to store the strings - can you just output them as you generate them?

Comment: What is the highest value of n? How would you represent n = 37 (10num +26alpha + 1)?

Answer (score 0):

This code will give you an idea about how to approach these problems recursively. Because of the recursive nature it will have a quite a lot of duplicates. I leave that to you to remove those.Also it prints output for all n

```
public void GetMaxPerm(int[] array, int k, List<int> output, int start, int end)
    {
        string str = GetString(output);
        Console.WriteLine(str);
        if (k == end)
        {

            return;
        }
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
        {
            output.Add(array[i]);
            GetMaxPerm(array, k + 1, output, start , end);
            output.Remove(array[i]);
            GetMaxPerm(array, k + 1, output, start, end);
        }

        return;

    }

    private string GetString(List<int> output)
    {
        string opString = String.Empty;
        foreach (var str in output)
        {
            opString = opString + String.Format(" {0} ", str);
        }
            return opString;
    }
```

Test Code :

```
 [TestMethod()]
    public void GetMaxTest1()
    {
        int[] array = new[] { 0, 1, 2 };
        Class obj = new Class();
        List<int> output = new List<int>();
        obj.GetMaxPerm(array, 0, output, 0, 3);
    }
```

Check this [Gist](http://csharppad.com/gist/b07bf57f3b3cb16c701a3cc21986bb11)